# Appending SQLite / MySQL table with Python Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way in Pandas to update an existing SQL database with a column (not row). I've used `df.to_sql` to create tables and know of the `if_exists='append'` parameter. But is there a way to append columns? Trying to avoid writing `cur.executemany`.

Comment: Try creating new table with all needed columns and append data from previous table on prior columns.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid unecessary writes. Costly when the data gets big.

Comment: Columns are structural components of tables, part of database schema especially if they are indices. As such, they should not be regularly added, dropped, changed on the fly like rows (data components). Can you not anticipate all columns beforehand and append from pandas to needed fields? Likely, you may not be normalizing appropriately, keeping very wide instead of long columns in third norm.

Comment: I'm adding columns as I add features. I'd like to store these in the same table rather than recompute them each time.

Comment: That is fine but anticipate all features. Or create a one-to-many Features table. Databases should be planned and designed prior to use. Please post more info of your context.